# Sql data fragmentation

Tags: mysql, sql, selenium

[image]

Brand       Model

Audi R8     NULL
Audi RS2    NULL

> My Dream

Brand       Model

Audi        R8
Audi        RS2

> Hello, the model data in this table (A8, RS2,RS4..)how can I separate it from the brand and write it in the model column?

Comment: Please remove the image and add the data as text. Which dbms are you using ?

Comment: HeidiSql and MySql Front

Comment: Is there always a space between brand and model and no other space? Or how to know where to split? Do you want to write a select only or do you want to update the model column? Should the brand column also be updated?

Comment: Yes, the brand column should also be updated, the brand should only be Audi, and the model should be A1.

Comment: Yes, there is a gap.

Comment: Ok, please explain how/where to split brand and model. In your few sample rows, this can just be done using the space. Is this always the case for ALL rows in your table? Is it save there don't appear other spaces within brand or model and there is always a space between brand and model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the brand is separated by space with the model and contains no other space you can use substring_index.

Test it first,

```
select brand,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(brand,' ',-1) as model ,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(brand,' ',+1) as new_brand 
from my_table;
```

To update the table,

```
update my_table
set model = SUBSTRING_INDEX(brand,' ',-1) , 
    brand= SUBSTRING_INDEX(brand,' ',+1)
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/B7hRHld-

*Edit*

To force the query to use only the rows containing one space you could use

```
update my_table
set model = SUBSTRING_INDEX(brand,' ',-1) , 
    brand= SUBSTRING_INDEX(brand,' ',+1)
where LENGTH(brand)-LENGTH(REPLACE(brand, ' ', '')) =1
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/wtZVAUTk

*Note*, the value `('Audi Rsq8 ')` isn't splited because it contains two spaces

Comment: You are a very good person, your help has touched me a lot. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have one last question

Comment: There are 35 fields in this table, when I run this query, there are just 3 columns. How can it affect the existing table and affect a certain number of data, we can think of it as the first ten. But I also have thousands of brand-models.

Comment: It was clear this will happen, therefore I refused to write an answer. Please ask your question in a way it can be answered without raising question 2, then question 3 etc. because you didn't provide sufficient information.

Comment: @B.12 The query will not affect any of other columns, but as I mentioned it expect only one space per row in the brand column to make the split. Now to enforce the query to use only the rows containing one space you can add a where clause `LENGTH(brand)-LENGTH(REPLACE(brand, ' ', '')) ` . I will add an explanation for this

Comment: @B.12 and please add all the clarification in the question, it can help other as well